# How to send the same alarmid when multiple days are set for a single alarm in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have set the alarm with notification for multiple days i.e. when I set a particular alarm for every Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday that particular alarm should show notification on every Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday. This is working fine. When I am setting an alarm for multiple days I am creating a timestamp and saving it in userinfo of notification.

So my problem is when for a particular it gets a day; Monday it creates a new alarmid and save it in the userinfo, and when it gets Tuesday it creates a new alarmid and saves in the userinfo object. Finally with Wednesday, I want that when I set a particular alarm for multiple days using the notification object  it should create only one alarmid for Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday not different alarmids.

This is my code:

```
-(void)scheduleNotification
{
    itemDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    timepicker = [[TTimePickerController alloc]init];

    double double_date = (double)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];     

      NSDate *now= [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:double_date];
    selectedWeek = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]arrayForKey:@"week"];
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"time"];
    NSInteger repeatCount = 7;
    today = [NSDate date];

    NSString *Stringdate;
    calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateFormatter *format = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
    format.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm";

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    dateFormat.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";


    NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
    timeFormat.dateFormat = @"hh:mm";

    for (NSDate *date in array)

    {
        if ([date isEqualToDate:now]) 
        {
            itemDate = date;
            NSLog(@"%@",itemDate);
        } 
        else if([date earlierDate:now]){
            itemDate = date;

        }
        else if([date laterDate:now])
        {
            itemDate =date;
        }

    }

    app.newtest = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] autorelease];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < repeatCount; i++) {
        date1 = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval:i * 24 * 60 * 60];
        dateComponents = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date1];
        if ([selectedWeek containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:dateComponents.weekday - 1]]) {
            NSLog(@"weekday:%d",dateComponents.weekday);
            // Adding the local notification.
            Stringdate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
                          [dateFormat stringFromDate:date1],
                          [timeFormat stringFromDate:itemDate]];

            if ([today compare:[format dateFromString:Stringdate]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
                notification.fireDate = [format dateFromString:Stringdate];
                notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
                notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Notify:%@", Stringdate];
                notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
                notification.alertAction = @"Open";

                               //Here i am creating the alarmid 
                NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
                NSNumber *timeStampObj = [NSNumber numberWithInt:timeStamp];
                NSLog(@"%d",timeStampObj);

                am.AlarmID =(int)timeStampObj;
                NSLog(@"%@",am.AlarmID);


                app = (StopSnoozeAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
                [app.newtest setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:am.AlarmID]forKey:@"idtemp"];
                [app.newtest setObject:app.timerdate forKey:@"iddate"];     

                notification.userInfo = app.newtest;
                NSLog(@"notif userinfo:%@",notification.userInfo);
                //NSLog(@"notif userinfo:%@",notification.userInfo);

                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: This can be closed under the official close reason: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_.